Access kind cluster services from another Docker container
I've got a Kubernetes kind (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) cluster running locally and I put Postgres HA on it:
helm install postgres bitnami/postgresql-ha

That's all started up, and seems to be in the kind Docker network.
Then I have another app in it's on docker-compose.yaml file. I put all the services in the kind network and then referenced it in the yaml file:
networks:
  kind:
    external: true

I can see the Postgres services running with kubectl get services.
However when I run docker network inspect kind I can see all the docker-compose.yaml services and kind-control-plan, but no Postgres services.
I was hoping to see postgres-postgresql-ha-pgpool in there so I could call it from the other Docker containers.
What's missing here?

I wouldn't try to mix-and-match container systems.  Can you run your application in Kubernetes too?  Or the database in plain Docker without Kubernetes?

This was just for a quick test locally, otherwise I'm not mixing these up. Was hoping to do it without all that extra work.
